# React Native UWP (vnext) - Importing react-navigation-stack causes error: "Cannot read property 'Direction' of undefined"

Tags: react-native, uwp, react-native-windows

I'm currently working on a simple "hello-world" type project and it works fine on both Android and UWP up until i use `import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';` in `App.js`. The app still works in Android but in UWP the app screen is just white, and the chrome debugger gives me the following error messages:

`...\ReactNative\MyApp_ReactNative\node_modules\react-native-windows\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:86 Cannot read property 'Direction' of undefined`

`...\MyApp_ReactNative\node_modules\react-native-windows\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:86 Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)`

I have been struggling with this problem for days now and I simply can't find any solutions to this. I am suspecting that the vnext version of react-native-windows does not support react-navigation-stack, or that maybe there's a previous version of react-navigation-stack I need to use for it to work with UWP.

I am completely new to React, and React Native, so please keep explanations somewhat simple . To reproduce, follow this guide https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-windows/blob/master/vnext/docs/GettingStarted.md, and then the first part of https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation untill you get to the part about react-navigation-stack. If there's any more info I can give that will be helpful I can gladly provide it.

Here's my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp_ReactNative",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.60.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-screens": "1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-windows": "0.60.0-vnext.74",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "rnpm-plugin-windows": "^0.3.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.6.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: If anyone stumbles over this question because they have the same problem: I couldn't find a solution to this. I tried downgrading RN and react-navigation-stack but it just broke the entire project (I probably did something wrong in this process). I ended up scrapping UWP entirely and created a new project using the newest version of RN. A possible work-around could be using createDrawerNavigator from the react-navigation-drawer library, which seems to work almost just like the stack. I haven't tried it out with UWP yet because of an impending deadline, I'll update if I eventually do.